# How do I upgrade the OpenId4Java jar version in the OpenID plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, openid, openid4java

I have installed the [OpenID plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/openid) (v0.4.3) for my Grails(v2.0.1) app but I am having trouble authenticating with Google as the OpenID provider.

I believe the problem is that OpenId4Java v0.9.4 doesn't handle Google's response properly. I read this somewhere the other day but can't find a reference at the moment (will edit when I find it).

So I want to upgrade the version of the OpenId4Java jar that the plugin has with a later version. But I am not sure where/how to do this.

In the `<home dir>/.grails/2.0.1/projects/<my project>/plugins/openid-0.4.3/lib` folder the jar is `java-openid-sxip-0.9.4.jar`. And the one I find in the recommended download from http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/ is `openid4java-0.9.6.jar`.

I've never had to replace a jar supplied by a plugin before so I'm just wondering where I should put the 0.9.6 jar, and how I get my app to recognise it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that installing version 0.4.4 (released late May 2012) of the OpenID plugin does the trick. It comes with `openid4java-nodeps-0.9.6.jar` instead of `java-openid-sxip-0.9.4.jar` meaning the newer version (v0.9.6) of OpenId4Java is used.